# React Fullpage TypeError undefined when state changes in app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the state changes (mainly via a onClick event) in the React app the React fullpage package throws a TypeError for the following scroll events causing a massive performance decrease.

I've tried multiple methods to bind the state change to the click event but each one throws the same fault. I've also tried Fullpage in multiple configuations, each resulting in the same issue.

```
<ReactFullpage
    scrollBar
    licenseKey={'YOUR_KEY_HERE'}
    scrollingSpeed={500}
    render={comp => (
        <Fragment>
            <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
                <div className={this.state.toggle ? "overlay section" : "section">
                    <div onClick={() => this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle})}>Toggle state</div>
                 </div>
             </ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
         </Fragment>
     )}
/>
```

This should just change the state that I'm asking it to. Instead I get

```
TypeError: e is undefined     react-fullpage.js:2875
    n react-fullpage.js:2875
    _n react-fullpage.js:2885
    fe react-fullpage.js:3572
    He react-fullpage.js:3800
    je react-fullpage.js:3850
```

which happens for every scroll event that follows the change in state, which results in the console getting filled with errors and the package itself makes the app unuseable.

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this or any other packages that provide similar functionality then I'm all ears. Thanks

Comment: Its probably issue with fat-arrow and `this` inside the wrapper causing the issue

Comment: share this code block react-fullpage.js:2875 to check this error - TypeError: e is undefined     react-fullpage.js:2875

Comment: @KannanG here is the code where the log says the error is occuring (https://imgur.com/a/osrboUk)

Comment: this error is not in the cope snippet. please share some code for us to see and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, the "section" class was being overwritten on the state change causing fullpage to fault. Proof of this @ https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lumiere-h50zs if anyone has any other ideas I'd be happy to hear.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the issue you are having here is that you are doing

```
 this.setState(toggle: !this.state.toggle)
```

Where as I believe what you want to do is

```
 this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle})
```

Because React state is actually an object.
However there might be some other issue in your application as *e* doesn't exist in your component.

Comment: This was a typo when creating the question, thank you for picking it up anyway